# AWS Glue Python Shell connectivity issue with Oracle cx_Oracle

Tags: python-3.x, aws-glue, cx-oracle

While trying to connect to Oracle Database using Python shell script on AWS Glue I get the following error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/glue-python-scripts-vr6vd3y0/patronage_report.py", line 120, in check_on_demand_data
File "/tmp/glue-python-scripts-vr6vd3y0/patronage_report.py", line 436, in db_oracle_connection
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I have placed the following libraries in s3 bucket and specified the path in job properties as well but still the same issue.

cx_Oracle-8.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl, libclntsh.so

Comment: libclntsh.so is not the only library required; it will load some other Oracle libraries.  You can run ldd on it to find them, or check the manual https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lacli/instant-client-shared-libraries.html#GUID-1D801ED9-D7DD-42D7-8BA1-1993A6CD6356  I can't comment on the AWS setup or whether you have the files in the right places.

Comment: Python library path is as follows
s3://nsw-transport-dev01-work/monthly-patronage-report/lib/cx_Oracle-8.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl,s3://nsw-transport-dev01-work/monthly-patronage-report/lib/libclntsh.so,s3://nsw-transport-dev01-work/monthly-patronage-report/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1

Comment: Where does AWS Glue search for Oracle client libraries?